# How would I use a QStyledItemDelegate to make only part of a view editable?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

I'm trying to teach myself how to use the `QStyledItemDelegate` class correctly. Qt's got a fantastic example that I read here: [Qt Spin Box Delegate Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html).

But here's a question I can't seem to answer. Let's take a look at their example screenshot.

[image: Qt Spin Box Delegate Screenshot]

How would I write `SpinBoxDelegate` in their example such that I could only edit part of the data, say, only items in column 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're already re-implementing `QAbstractItemDelegate::createEditor()`

The simplest way to indicate that a certain index in your table shouldn't be editable is to return `NULL` from this function, for example:

```
QWidget *QAbstractItemDelegate::createEditor( QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index )
{
  if( index.column() == 0 )
    return NULL;

  return new QSpinBox( parent );
}
```

You can get fancier by stuffing additional information in your model and retrieving it with `QModelIndex::data()`

Comment: That did the trick. I was a little worried that I'd crash the program by returning a null pointer...I didn't realize that `QAbstractItemDelegate` is smart enough to check for one. Thanks!

Comment: Much better when an entire column in a `QTableWidget` needs to be read-only; other option to setting every `QTableWidgetItem::flag` is not very elegant and fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

The regular way to indicate that certain parts of a model are not editable is to reimplement `QAbstractItemModel::flags()` in your model to exclude the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag.